# 18.04 Live session not displaying. "Mode Unsupported" message on any screen

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, multiple-monitors, live-usb

I've been trying to boot into a live session so I can use gparted to upgrade to a larger SSD, but I've only been able to get into it once. I let it suspend by accident that one time and I wasn't able to get back into it. After rebooting manually, my display ports weren't working, so I switched both inputs to HDMI. Now every time I try to get into a live session, either of my monitors display the message "Mode Unsupported". I can only get as far as "Try ubuntu before installing" after which the screens go black, or just the one screen since I tried it with just one of two plugged in.

I also have to boot into the USB through UEFI which might cause issues? Setting the boot sequence to USB first in Legacy BIOS doesn't work.

Did something break in the grub when I rebooted that one time? I've tried a number of times, and after each failed attempt my monitors (dual screen) revert to "stock" settings, but regain my custom settings once logged in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3328 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected 768x1366+0+74 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1150mm x 650mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1920x1080     59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1280x720      59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94    59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1440+768+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   2560x1440    144.00*+ 119.99    59.95  
   1920x1080    120.00   119.88    60.00    60.00    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.93    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS x86_64

Host: Precision T3610 00 (Dell)

Kernel: 5.4.0-62-generic

CPU: Intel Xeon E5-1650 v2

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Ti

Comment: There can be many reasons a Bootable USB does not Boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot